# SignalR Content dont update if send to Client.Caller

Tags: c#, signalr

Hello and thanks for reading this.

This is my NotificationHub.cs

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> Users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    private static List<User> UserList = new List<User>();

    Int16 totalNewMessages = 0;

    string UserID;

    [HubMethodName("check")]
    public Task Check(string id)
    {
        string profileId = id; //Context.QueryString["id"];
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        var user = Users.GetOrAdd(profileId, _ => new User
        {
            ProfileId = profileId,
            ConnectionIds = id
        });
        lock (user.ConnectionIds)
        {
            Groups.Add(connectionId, user.ProfileId);
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    [HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
    public Task SendNotifications(string id)
    {
        UserID = id;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT NotificationNumber FROM [dbo].[NotificationStatus] WHERE UserID=" + UserID;

            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)

                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                dt.Load(reader);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    totalNewMessages = Int16.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["NotificationNumber"].ToString());

                }

            }

        }

        User CurrentUser = UserList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProfileId == UserID);

        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

        //return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
        return context.Clients.Client(Users.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProfileId == UserID).ConnectionIds).RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);

    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            NotificationHub nHub = new NotificationHub();
            nHub.SendNotifications(UserID);

        }

    }
}
```

These 2 lines is what I want to focus on.

```
//return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
        return context.Clients.Client(Users.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProfileId == UserID).ConnectionIds).RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
```

If i use the first line it returns the totalNewMessages back to ALL people on the website, but i only want to to return back to the user that requested it.

The second line is my attempt to return the totalNewMessages back tot he specific user, but it dont work.

How can i return the totalNewMessages Back to only the specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this problem a while back. I got it working by returning the messages depending on the user who's logged in

```
string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
return context.Clients.User(userName).RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
```

Also look into [parameterized](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) queries to prevent sql injection. There's a handy documentation for what you're trying to achieve [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)